# iScroll 4: Disable anchors when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, iscroll

iScroll 4: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

I would to know if it is possible to prevent the mouse release event on anchors (ie follow link) if the release happens after scrolling.
In other words, i would that anchors works only if i make a single, non dragging, click.

The problem is when i have a big image within an  tag and if i scroll and release inside the img area, then the link is followed, but this is not the intended behavior.

The ideal solution would be to return false on mouse release if it happens after dragging.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the code where you initiate iScroll

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

It should prevent links from firing whilst the user is scrolling

Hope this helps!